# Simulate a SSL client in java

Tags: java, ssl

I have a question regarding ssl client in java.
In case of Browser, a client hello request is initiated having ciphers suites it supports, version number etc. and server responds with a server hello having the cipher suite which would be used for this session.

I think a session (`jsessionId`) is created at this time (server hello) if one is not present in client hello (which means `jsessionId` is sent to client unprotected(?))

Once this process is completed browser makes a https request as required and browser encrypts it using encryption algorithm mentioned in the cipher suite returned in server hello.

If i have to do it in java I can use SSLSocket to do the handshake and associate a handler in `addHandshakeCompletedListener` method.

So, once the handshake is completed, control comes to `addHandshakeCompletedListener` callback method.

So, if now i need to make a ssl request i will have to use `HttpsURLConnection` (?) and create a request.

My question is -How does HttpsURLConnection  know about the encryption algorithm and then encrypts using that?

Can i encrypt it myself using the encryption algorithm in cipher suite and post it over a normal http connection (`HttpURLConnection` (?)). Will it work?

I know it is a complex structure - we have to calculate mac and then append before we encrypt the data. Does `HttpsURLConnection`  does all this?

How is session maintained? How does `HttpsURLConnection`   know that this connection has already been initiated and handshake procedures have already been completed?

I am not able to correlate all this? Any help would be appreciated! If possible please provide an example to explain.

Comment: jsessionID is an upper level entity and is beyond ssl handshake (server hello). It is in http(s) layer but not in socket layer (ssl)

Comment: Your title says 'simulate an SSL client in Java'. What does this mean? Why would you want to simulate something that Java can already do?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a question regarding ssl client in java. In case of Browser, a client hello request is initiated having ciphers suites it supports, version number etc. and server responds with a server hello having the cipher suite which would be used for this session.

Correct.

> I think a session (jsessionId) is created at this time (server hello) if one is not present in client hello (which means jsessionId is sent to client unprotected(?))

No. That's part of HTTPS, not SSL, and it happens after the SSL handshake is complete.

> Once this process is completed browser makes a https request as required and browser encrypts it using encryption algorithm mentioned in the cipher suite returned in server hello.

Correct.

> If i have to do it in java I can use SSLSocket to do the handshake and associate a handler in addHandshakeCompletedListener method.

If you have to do HTTPS in Java all you need is an `HttpsURLConnection`. You don't need an `SSLSocket` as well.

> So, once the handshake is completed, control comes to addHandshakeCompletedListener callback method.

That's only for the purpose of verifying the peer identity, and it doesn't happen in `HttpsURLConnection`.

> So, if now i need to make a ssl request i will have to use HttpsURLConnection (?) and create a request.

This is where you should start. Everything above this point is irrelevant to you.

> My question is -How does HttpsURLConnection know about the encryption algorithm and then encrypts using that?

It doesn't. It uses an `SSLSocket` internally which does all that.

> Can i encrypt it myself using the encryption algorithm in cipher suite and post it over a normal http connection (HttpURLConnection (?)). Will it work?

No and no. None of this is necessary. It is all done for you.

> I know it is a complex structure - we have to calculate mac and then append before we encrypt the data. Does HttpsURLConnection does all this?

No, `SSLSocket` does it.

> How is session maintained?

Which session? There are two: an SSL session and an HTTPS session. The SSL session is maintained by the underlying SSLContext, the HTTPS session by the server via the jsessionid cookie.

> How does HttpsURLConnection know that this connection has already been initiated and handshake procedures have already been completed?

Because it used an `SSLSocket` to do so.

> I am not able to correlate all this? Any help would be appreciated! If possible please provide an example to explain.

Too broad.

Answer (score -1):

> So, if now i need to make a ssl request i will have to use
>   HttpsURLConnection (?) and create a request.
>
> My question is -How does HttpsURLConnection know about the encryption
>   algorithm and then encrypts using that?

Yes you have to use HttpsURLConnection. But you dont have to do it explicitly. `new URL("https://google.pl").openConnection();` is more then enough.

In Server Hello, server anounces what encrypiton it can accept. All encryption methods have to "announce" themselves so the server knows how to interpret them. 
So when you initiatle the connection, servers says what it can handle, client choose one of the cipers and ciper the data using it. At the beginning of the connection, client announces what suite will it use.

This information can be public to this is not a problem that this is sent as plaintext. The point is, to exchange the symetric key between client in server in private way, so the rest of communication can be ciphered usint that key.

> How is session maintained? How does HttpsURLConnection know that this
>   connection has already been initiated and handshake procedures have
>   already been completed?

Well SSL stands for Secure Socket Layer. It means that data transmit and received is ciphered, decrypted on raw socket(streams) level; You can open SSL connection to transmit data from point to point not only via Https

There is no "session". As long as you open a connection, you got 2 streams. Input and Output. As long as those are open, you can write data or read from them. Once they are closed, you will have to initiate another connection.

Every Http request is a new connection (unless Keep-Alive is sent). JsessionId for example, or php's sessionid is to identity that you are the same client that made requests earlier so it can "simulate" constant connection.

Comment: What i am assuming is that Server/Client hello transaction is a different connection than the actual request and since it is build atop http, it is stateless. So, how does first request knows about what was negotiated in client/server hello?

Comment: This is what you dont understand. It is not SSL build otop of http, but https is build atop SSL. Hanshake is on socket layer (ssl). Actual http data (request) is sent after secure connection is established trough secure sockets. So basicly single request is -> connect -> do ssl handshke -> exchange keys -> establish secure channel -> HTTPS transmit request data -> receive response.

Comment: As for "So, how does first request knows about what was negotiated in client/server hello" - it does not know. It is plain new connection with all handshakes and stuff (read my response).

Comment: okay :( , So once server decides on a cipher suite and sends it to client and when it gets next request (say for a resource) from client, How does server know which cipher suit to use? Is cipher suite included in each request OR server associate it to session and get it from there everytime?

Comment: Server says to the client - Hey, I can accept ciphers X,Y,Z and nothing more. Client responses then - Ok I will use Y ciper. And then client starts to transmit data. There is nothing in a way to use different ciphere between requests. Server application usess session identifiers, (jsession id, phpsession id) to identify and "pair" or "group" multiple connections and requests into single, logic session (or threat them as single continous connection.

Comment: Okay so you are saying is that this cipher information and other related information is stored in session?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109076/discussion-between-ouney-and-antoniossss).

Comment: @Antoniossss The client announces the cipher suites and the server chooses one. You have that back to front.

Comment: @EJP you are right, cipher announcements are made during Client Hello (and that is the first step), server does the same on Server Hello. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Antoniossss The TLS protocol does allow for sessions to be resumed, see [RFC 5246](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246), section 7.3: _"When the client and server decide to resume a previous session or duplicate an existing session (instead of negotiating new security parameters), the message flow is as follows: ..."_

Comment: @MikeHarris Yes, indeed. But if we would like to broke all protocols down into a details, we would be able to write a book. The main abstract idea and flow related to OPs question and thoughts are maintainer. Dont you think? Thanks for pointing that out as well.

Comment: @Antoniossss If you're going to mention these details get them right. The server does not 'do the same on server hello'. It chooses a single cipher suite.

Comment: @EJP I did not argue with you on that.

Comment: You said 'the server does the same'. It doesn't.